# AsyncTask return the first Array from the server, the second array is always full of zeros

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask

I am creating a game where with a button listener, server creates an array of integers and return them into the client.

**Here you can see the code from the button listener:**

```
rollDiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roll_dice);
    rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            rollDice();

            new DiceTask() {

                @Override
                public void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
                    tempArray = result;
                    printDice(tempArray,pDice);
                    clickableDice(pDice);
                }
            }.execute(socket);

        }
    });
```

The rollDice(); method just sends a String to the server to notify him that he can roll the dice.

**The Dice Roll into the server:**

```
while(running) {
                String st = input.readLine();

                if (st.equals("dice")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < diceRolled.length; i++) {
                        diceRolled[i] = (int) ( 1 + Math.random() * 6);
                        System.out.print(diceRolled[i] + " ");
                    }
                    output.writeObject(diceRolled);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

**And the code from my AsyncTask, DiceTask(), is this:**

```
public class DiceTask extends AsyncTask<Socket, Void, int[]> {

private int[] arrayFromServer = new int[8];

public DiceTask() {

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected int[] doInBackground(Socket...params) {
    Socket soc = params[0];


        ObjectInputStream ois;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            arrayFromServer = (int[]) (ois.readObject());
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayFromServer;
}
```

The first time I am pressing the button I can confirm that the array in the server is the same with the array in my client, but the second time, the array in 8 zeros in my client when I can see the 8 normal dice into the server. What I am doing wrong? Where is my mistake?

**LOGCAT:**

```
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=-1
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.pickominoclient.GameActivity.printDice(GameActivity.java:214)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.pickominoclient.GameActivity$2$1.onPostExecute(GameActivity.java:84)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.pickominoclient.GameActivity$2$1.onPostExecute(GameActivity.java:1)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-08 16:07:25.070: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit**

**PrintDice code:**

```
public void printDice(int[] array1, ImageView[] array2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array2[i].setImageResource(diceImages[array1[i] - 1]);
        array2[i].setTag(array1[i]);
        array2[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**diceImages array:**

```
private final int[] diceImages = new int[] {R.drawable.dice_one, R.drawable.dice_two, R.drawable.dice_three, 
        R.drawable.dice_four, R.drawable.dice_five, R.drawable.dice_pico };
```

Comment: It looks like the logcat is saying you're trying to print an item at index -1 in the tempArray variable. What are pDice and the printDice(tempArray, pDice) function?

Comment: @daentech thanks for your reply. Yeah it says that array is out of bounds because my array is full of 0. When I am printing the dice I need some values for my dice. I will edit my post to add the code.